# Long to wide: two variables

Tags: r, database

I have a large dataset of health records that I am trying to get from long to wide format. Currently it is in this format.

| eid | code | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person_1 | 123 | 2006-07-12 |
| Person_1 | 1555 | 2006-07-12 |
| Person_1 | 1989 | 2009-08-12 |
| Person_2 | 1020 | 2008-09-12 |
| Person_2 | 1220 | 2008-07-15 |
| Person_2 | 12929 | 2020-07-22 |

I would like it in this format:

```
|eid | Code_1 | date_1 | code_2 | date_2 | code_3 | date_3|
```

and so on. I was struggling with this in reshaping.

Many thanks

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(eid) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(code, date))`